# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when calling count on fetched objects

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm getting a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error when this code gets called `NSLog(@"Count: %@", [fetchedObjects count]);`. It seems like it is because the objects are not yet fetched or something like that because fetchedObjects is not `nil`. I noticed that if I change `count` for `lastObject` it works and the following gets printed in the console

`<Albums: 0x4dc7120> (entity: Albums; id: 0x4d9ad60 <x-coredata://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Albums/p1> ; data: <fault>)`

**Code**

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Albums" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
if (fetchedObjects != nil) {
    NSLog(@"objects is not nil");
}

NSLog(@"Count: %@", [fetchedObjects lastObject]);
for (Albums *info in fetchedObjects) {
    NSLog(@"Album: %@", info);
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", info.name);
}        
[fetchRequest release];
```

If any of you guys have any pointers, that would be great.

Thank you!

**Update**

I realized the format specifier should be %d or %i, my mistake. However I get the same error when I call the count function in the numbersOfRowsInSection method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%d` or `%i` as the *format specifiers* to print *int* values.

```
NSLog(@"Count: %d", [fetchedObjects count]);
```

Comment: You are right, however I get the exact same error when I call the count function on its own, what would be the problem then?

Comment: Empty stack is right, you are printing the count of fetched objects that must be an integer value and you are logging it with %@ which is for object ,so you should go with  %d to print the value.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is pretty much right:

```
NSLog(@"Count: %d", [fetchedObjects count]);
```

you also need to check the type of fetchedObjects

```
[fetchedObjects isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]];
```

and then call the count method, it will work fine.

Comment: I thought the executeFetchRequest function was suppose to return a NSArray? I still need to specify I want a NSArray?

Comment: Yes I believe the value you are storing is not an array. Means you are getting something else by [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]; and that's why count is crashing, It can be fruitful guess. You just try it if it helps.